# How to display storage content in laravel 5.3 from storage folder?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I can't display image or playing mp3 file.

On my localhost all files images, mp3 work fine in symbolic link at `public/storage`

When I moved to the share hosting can't work

This is sample code for image tag

```
<img class="colortooltip" src="{{asset($track->image)}}"  alt="{{$track->Name}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{$track->Name}}">
```

this is output error

[image]

Comment: What is the value of $track->image?

Comment: is a path 
storage/images/avatars/artists/f9dc92344b57ec6b0bcb3ce601f9d134.jpeg

Comment: When you symlink do you symlink so that you the server path is /public/storage/...?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you symlink could be incorrect you are likely symlinking storage as public when you should be symlinking storage into public e.g.

public -> storage

and it should be (looking at the URL given)
public/storage

Comment: i have been laravel command for making symlinking  php artisan storage:link

Comment: I am sorry I can't help any further, as I understand Laravel Artisan Commands can be a little bit weird on shared hosting and it can be unique to each provider. Very sorry I can't help further